# Error when doing simple event\delegate calls when generic class is involved

Tags: c#, events, generics

The following classes

```
public class PagedItemList<T>
{
    public delegate void PageChanged(int newPage);

    public event PageChanged PageChangedEvent;
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public void SetupWithPagedList<T>(PagedItemList<T> list)
    {
        list.PageChangedEvent += new PagedItemList<T>.PageChanged(NotifyPageChanged);
    }

    public void NotifyPageChanged(int newPage) { }
}
```

Throws the error:

> InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type

When I try to add a listener to the event as seen in the example above.

The call to SetupWithPagedList is correctly parametrized:

```
obj.SetupWithPagedList<Monster>(pagedMonstersList)
```

I have done events and delegates a lot before, the only difference here is that there is a `<T>` involved in this class. Has anyone had issues doing events and delegates with templates?

Comment: I did a test where I removed the paramaterization and it does work. So not sure what I am doing wrong but its clearly related to that.

Comment: how do you declare `pagedMonstersList`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem in this case is with, the instances. The first question I made when I saw your `PagedItemListCode` was, why `SetupWithPagedList` is not an static method, and I checked that you are calling the `NotifyPageChanged` method in the instance of the class. I do not know the logic behind the problem, but maybe the right way is like this:

```
public static void SetupWithPagedList<T>(PagedItemList<T> list)
{
    list.PageChangedEvent += new PagedItemList<T>.PageChanged(list.NotifyPageChanged);
}
```

Note that the instance of the class maybe is not the same instance of the object that is passed to the `SetupWithPagedList` method. Maybe the class is `PagedItemList<A>` and the method parameter is `PagedItemList<Monster>`. Maybe the class do not need to be generic. Check it.

---

**EDIT**

---

I tried your code and works perfect:

```
var p = new PagedItemList<int>();
var sc = new SomeClass();
sc.SetupWithPagedList(p);
p.RaisPageChanged(5);
```

...

```
public class PagedItemList<T>
{
    public delegate void PageChanged(int newPage);

    public event PageChanged PageChangedEvent;

    public void RaisPageChanged(int page)
    {
        if (PageChangedEvent != null)
            PageChangedEvent(page);
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public void SetupWithPagedList<T>(PagedItemList<T> list)
    {
        list.PageChangedEvent += new PagedItemList<T>.PageChanged(NotifyPageChanged);
    }

    public void NotifyPageChanged(int newPage)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Page: ",newPage);
    }
}
```

Check it, maybe is something else.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up my example. It was supposed to be 2 seperate classes. I fixed the example. I did verify that the call being passed in is of the same paramater type.